# MIgrations and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm developing a Rails application with Rspec for unit testing.

Weeks ago, Rspec used to migrate the database to the last version automatically when executing 'rake spec', but now it doesn't do it automatically, I have to implement everything for myself.

This happens in test environment, because my development data doesn't desappear.

Is my fault? I didn't change anything, I think :)

Comment: are you getting any errors when you try and execute "rake spec"?

Comment: If I generate migrations, a "You have pending migrations" raises. At this point I have to migrate the database by myself, and rerun "rake spec"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Typically what I do is use an alias command that runs both migrate and prepares the test database.

```
rake db:migrate && rake db:test:prepare
```

In your .bashrc just create an alias command like so and then run migrate_databases whenever you need to.

```
alias migrate_databases='rake db:migrate && rake db:test:prepare'
```

Comment: I prefer solve the problem instead of hide it, but thanks.

BTW, sorry for answer a month later :)

Answer (score 11):

My solution for Rails 4:

in `spec/spec_helper.rb` or anywhere in testing environment initialization code:

```
# Automigrate if needs migration
if ActiveRecord::Migrator.needs_migration?
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(File.join(Rails.root, 'db/migrate'))
end
```

**UPD:** As Dorian kindly pointed out in comments, you don't need to check separately if there are any pending migrations, because `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate` already does this behind the scenes. So you can effectively use just this one line:

```
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(File.join(Rails.root, 'db/migrate'))
```

Comment: the `db:test:clone` has deprecated in Rails 4.1

Comment: You do two SQL requests instead of just one by running `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(File.join(Rails.root, 'db/migrate'))` for the behavior and a shorter code.

Answer (score 8):

Rails 4.1 forward you can use:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
```

Add at the top of your `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb` and you're good to go. [More info here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks).

Comment: Can you give me some detail as to how it doesn't work? Does it throw an error of some sort? You may need to make sure your migrations are run in dev mode as well in order for it to work.

Comment: It throws error when I create a new migration and then run rspec

Comment: You ran the migration first with `rake db:migrate`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workaround:

Rakefile:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
require "rspec/core/rake_task"

MyApp::Application.load_tasks

desc "Run specs"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)

task :run_specs => ['db:test:clone', :spec] do

end

task :default => :run_specs
```

Then I run $ rake run_specs

for some reason default task doesn't default to run_specs

Answer (score 0):

See if you have the following in your spec_helper.rb? Everytime you run specs, RSpec checks if there are pending migrations.

```
#Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
#If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works even when Rails is not loaded and only does one SQL query most of the time.

```
if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migrator)
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'migrate'))
end
```